# Google safe browse API lookup Node.js

Tags: node.js, safe-browsing

I am having trouble getting a google safe search lookup working. Here is the code I am trying and I am always getting `{}` in the response

```
var request = require("request-promise")

var body = {
  "client": {
    "clientId":      "myclientid",
    "clientVersion": "1.0"
  },
  "threatInfo": {
    "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE"],
    "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS", "LINUX"],
    "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
    "threatEntries": [
      {"url": "http://some-malicious-url"}
    ]
  }
}

var options = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  },
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=my-api-key",
  form: body
}


request(options).then(function (data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

Not sure if I understood the docs correctly or if I am missing any param from my request. I have tried with different urls. Tried searching for malicious urls form web which were identified by my browser as malicious but those also returned blank response. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#http-post-request) I am following

I also tried their `threatLists:list` API and that always gives an error

```
curl -XGET https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatLists:list?key=my_api_key
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v4/threatLists:list?key=my_api_key</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Answer (score 2):

**threatLists working example:**

threatLists works without `:list`. e.g. `curl https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatLists?key=YOUR_KEY`

**threatMatches working example:**

Method: POST

Content-Type:application/json

https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=YOUR_KEY

Body:

`{
  "client": {
    "clientId": "testing",
    "clientVersion": "0.0.1"
  },
  "threatInfo": {
    "threatTypes": ["MALWARE","SOCIAL_ENGINEERING","UNWANTED_SOFTWARE","MALICIOUS_BINARY"],
    "platformTypes": ["ANY_PLATFORM"],
    "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
    "threatEntries": [
      {"url": "http://goooogleadsence.biz/"}
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. I have the same...

It seems Chrome browser has an other (more accurate) source for safe browsing. Maybe they keep these fresh data exclusively for some specific clients.
The result is the same whatever lookup protocol version you can use.
And this is the same if you use the update API.

If someone knows, really, why... I am very interested in this information.

Comment: But so far I haven't been able to identify any malicious url. Also, their `threatLists:list` API gives an error always. Any idea about that ?

Comment: got it working with a couple of urls finally. I did not find it much useful since it could not detect most of the malicious urls that Chrome could detect

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are appending "/" in you URLs in the request. It is important to do that.

In this case, your URL would become `http://some-malicious-url/`.

Let me know if this works!